# Emacs line numbering performance

Tags: performance, emacs, line-numbers

I've tried `linum` and `nlinum`. Both have dreadful performance on files with 100k+ lines.

```
$ for x in {1.100000}; do echo $x; done > 100k.txt
$ emacs -q 100k.txt
M-x load-library linum
M-x linum-mode
M-> ;; it's not too bad to go to end of file
M-< ;; now this completely locks up emacs
```

The same operation with editors like `joe` is instantaneous.

Is there any solution other than to turn off line numbers with big files (exactly the type of files that you want to navigate with line numbers - I have in mind locating error lines in concatenated Javascript files)?

Or just use a different editor?

Comment: The line number is shown in the mode line.

Comment: This is instantaneous for me on Emacs 24.3.50.1

Comment: @Tyler it is not instantaneous for me, running 24.3.1 on Ubuntu precise 3.5.0-40-generic, and with default config loaded (as you can see, I'm using -q). Running in rxvt window.

Comment: @abo-abo the mode line is too big a visual gap to be scanning back and forth between cursor

Comment: @Tyler I'm using Damien Cassou's PPA to get a semi-recent emacs on Ubuntu. Do you know how I can get yet a more recent version without having to build it myself?

Comment: I've found that emacs bug 14259 is relevant, reported in April. Simply setting window margin is enough to trigger slowdown (`(set-window-margins (selected-window) 2)`)

Comment: @BarryKelly sorry, I build my own from the bzr repo, running Debian. Not sure what's available for Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with Debian's 24.1 nor with Emacs's trunk (only tested with nlinum.el).

Comment: I'm using the regular Emacs 24.2.1 package on Ubuntu 13.04 and can't reproduce this problem, neither with Emacs running in its own graphical frame nor in a gnome-terminal.

Comment: @Rörd I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It's not just me, see http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2013-04/msg00577.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you found a bug, and you may report (report-emacs-bug) it.  As per Tyler comment, it may have been already solved.

Things that may help you in the meanwhile... `line-number-mode`, `goto-line`, `narrow-to-region` and this cheapo-number-my-lines-in-a-tmp-buffer trick:

```
(shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max)
    (concat "grep -n ^ " buffer-file-name)
    (get-buffer-create "*tmp-linum*") nil t)
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, both linum and its derivative nlinum number lines even if you don't see them. In the case of 100k+ lines, this can be slow if numbering an individual line takes more than a few tenths of a millisecond. For me, (Fedora 19, Emacs 24.3.1), there's no noticeable delay. Try [line-num.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/line-num.el), which only numbers lines that are currently visible and see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since Emacs 26 you should use `[global-]display-line-numbers-mode` instead.

For example:

```el
(global-display-line-numbers-mode 1)
```

or:

```el
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'display-line-numbers-mode)
```

(Or toggle them manually via <kbd>M-x</kbd>.)

The line numbering for these is implemented as part of the redisplay in C code, and is therefore efficient and performs well even with extremely large buffers.

To customize this feature use:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `display-line-numbers`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to .emacs file.

```
(global-linum-mode 1)
```

Comment: The question discounted `linum` as too slow.

Comment: The settings for M-x linum-mode and .emacs files are different.
I've been using it on centos with this setup so far and it works without any issues.

Comment: @phils What is the difference between the method you suggested and mine?
I think it is more advantageous to use it by presetting it in the initialization file.

Comment: One can, of course, put `(global-display-line-numbers-mode 1)` in the init file; I hadn't said that explicitly, but assumed people would know.  `global-display-line-numbers-mode` and `global-linum-mode` are two very different things.  The former is newer and (crucially for this question) very fast (because it's integrated into the core redisplay C code).  `linum-mode` does not have those benefits, and is much slower.    The only reason I gave your answer a down-vote was that your suggestion had been specifically mentioned in the question as one of the options which was too slow.